# Rider IDE improperly setting up .NET MAUI project

Tags: maui, rider

I have had success in the past with maui in rider and it actively works on my laptop right now. For some reason it just won't work on my desktop and I've now wasted far too much time trying to figure it out and I've given up.

Steps taken to try and resolve it so far:

1. uninstalled and reinstalled ALL IDE related files.
2. uninstalled and reinstalled ALL MAUI related files.
3. uninstalled and reinstalled ALL known .NET files
4. tried changing the targeted version, which just creates more errors that I also don't know how to solve.
   i) to solve these new errors I tried to reinstall some packages in nuget package manager which then began spitting out even more errors.

Things to consider:
I have no idea what msbuild is, what it does, or what version means what. I have looked into changing it, but then it messes up far more than just maui specific stuff

[image: this is the errors that happen without changing ANYTHING in the project]

[image: These are the options that I get when creating the MAUI project. notice that I cannot change the framework here. But when I get into the project it says I need to change the project to target the .NET 7.0 framework?!]

Comment: The error message suggests downloading and installing the .NET 8.0 SDK, and where you can do so. Have you done that?

Comment: I looked into it, but the error also says that it CANT target .net8

Comment: No, it says *the current SDK* can't target .NET 8.0. If you install the .NET 8.0 SDK, that won't be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it ended up being solved.
What finally solved this was locating the dotnet 8 that it was trying to use so desperately. Then deleting it in the file explorer (was around 8 GB) then I went into VS installer and used the repair feature. Then I reset Rider to default and now it just magically works....

This has been hours, and by far almost as bad as my Linux experiences in the past.